# plese help me with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Error

Tags: java, android, xml

```
com.google.android.gms E/LoadManifestTask: Can't find Chimera operation impl class com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.recovery.AccountRecoveryInitIntentOperation dropping operation

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.recovery.AccountRecoveryInitIntentOperation" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86, /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
  at bfs.run(SourceFile:1773)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.recovery.AccountRecoveryInitIntentOperation
  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
  ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

This is my .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="@drawable/sobiranje"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="397dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Score:  "
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="97dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/suma"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>    

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp">
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">    

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/number1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:editable="false"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">    

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/slika1"
                android:background="@drawable/plus_green"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/number2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:editable="false"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/slika2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/equal_green"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/number3"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:editable="true"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@drawable/button_green2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="try something other"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_green2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />   

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my java code

```
package com.example.tamara.kid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by tamara on 8/21/2016.
 */
public class plus extends MainActivity
{
    EditText t1,t2,t3; int num1,num2,num3; int suma; boolean flag=true;int i;
    EditText t4;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.plus);
        t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1);
        t2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2);
        t3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.number3);
        t4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.suma);
        suma=0;
        i=0;

        num1=(int)(Math.random()*99)+1;
        num2=(int)(Math.random()*99)+1;
        num3=num1+num2;
        t1.setText(num1);
        t2.setText(num2);
        t4.setText(suma);    
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(R.id.check==v.getId())
        {i++;
            if(num3==Integer.parseInt(t3.getText().toString()))
            {
                suma=suma+50;

                LayoutInflater mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
                View view= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.plus,null);
                Toast toast=new Toast(this);
                toast.setView(view);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                if(flag)
                {
                    toast.setText("You're right little genius");
                }
                else{
                    toast.setText("Correct Answer");}
                toast.show();
            }
            else
            {
                flag=false;
                LayoutInflater mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);
                View view= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.plus,null);
                Toast toast=new Toast(this);
                toast.setView(view);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setText("Wrong Answer");
                toast.show();
            }
            num1=(int)(Math.random()*99)+1;
            num2=(int)(Math.random()*99)+1;
            num3=num1+num2;
            t1.setText(num1);
            t2.setText(num2);
            t3.setText( " ");
            t4.setText(suma);
        }
        if(R.id.check==v.getId()){
            Intent i=new Intent(plus.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: This is painful to read. Consider editing your question so you might get some helpful responses. As it is currently your problem is unclear

Comment: are you using `hadoop-chimera` class? if so, show the directory structure and dependencies you added

Comment: I think problem is in your gradle file where you import library.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement 
   `multiDexEnabled true` in Default Congfig
In your gradel file if not work you can You can Compile
 `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`